# Setting Element value with javascript prior to form submit not sending POST data

Tags: javascript, zend-framework

I have a form which has several dynamically generated table data elements.Before submitting the form I set the value of two input element and submit the form with javascript.The input element value is set properly before sending the form and form is submited but I cant find the post value in my action.

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Austachal</td>
<td>2014-02-23 00:00:00</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input id="status" name="status "type="hidden">
<input id="id" name="id" type="hidden">
</form>

$('id').value=id;
$('status').value=status;
//alert(id +" >>> " +status); // its showing the value..OK
$('status_form').submit();
```

//in my action doesnt get anything.

```
echo $this->_getParam('id');
echo $this->_getParam('status');
```

**Questions edited**
I beg ur pardon, I forgot to mention that I m using Zend framework in socialengine, hence I m using mootools. the code here is NOT the actual code I m using which is much longer than it fits here.Its just what I actually want to achieve. I already told I can get the value as desired, the problem is NOT with getting element value, rather send it to my action controller using post.

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Thank u..I want to send the value/text of input element,which is set via javascript, to my action controller. The form is submitted by javascript prior to setting this value.The values are correctly set before triggering form submission as shown in firebug but is not found in action controller with _getParam().. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Thank u everybody for the effort. Actually the value was sent well but the problem was within the post verification.The post is ok but code inside the post wasnt working, so I thought maye its the post or the data with post.I was trying to do fetch table data nand update it, so i tried it in a transaction, which might have had the problem but it didnt SHOW any error,just not occurred. Thats why I coudnt figure it out.After I deleted the transaction and tried , it worked

```
if( $this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
      $db = Engine_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
      $db->beginTransaction(); // maybe this was the problem
      try
      {
        $room = Engine_Api::_()->getItem('room', $id);
        // Update status in the database
        $room->status=$new_status;
        $room->save();
        $db->commit();
      }

      catch( Exception $e )
      {
        $db->rollBack();
        throw $e;
      }

      $this->_forward('success');
    }
```

**By the way I M STILL NOT SURE if the transaction process was OK.I hope someone can pput some light on this**

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax for setting value in jquery is

```
$('#id').val(/*somevalue*/);
$('#status').val(/*somevalue*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('#id').val('id');
$('#status').val('status');
```

Answer (score 0):

do assignment operation in correct way and use '#' identifier for IDs

```
var id = $('#id').val();
var status = $('#status').val();
alert(id +" >>> " +status); 
$('status_form').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you verify if the request is post?

```
var_dump($this->getRequest()->isPost());
```

and if true verify your post values

```
var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost ());
```

Comment: yes indeed the request is post and verified, many others things are working inside that post verification.I mjust NOT getting the value right. But am I supposed to get the value this way?

Comment: This approach makes it possible to recover what is in post.
If I understand correctly, you are full of checks. Try var_dump method (getPost ()) at the entrance of your share (before any checks)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you have elements that go into post but not the id or the status.
try in the init function of your controller.
If it still does not pass, try to getPost in a plugin: public function routeStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {       
      var_dump($request->getPost());       
    }